# How to find total rows before required row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a text based mafia game and I am selected some GameRecords. The game records are all defined in the "users" table. For this example I am using "totalcrimes". I need to select all the rows from the users table and order it by totalcrimes and then find out which row each specific user is that is viewing the page.

If I was the user that was "ranked" 30th it would echo "30". The code I use to find the top 5 is here however I need to expand on it:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$FindCrimes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE status='Alive' AND robot = 0 ORDER BY `totalcrimes` DESC LIMIT 5");
while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($FindCrimes)){
    $Username = $Row['playername'];
    $TotalCrimes = number_format($Row['totalcrimes']);
    $i++;
        echo "
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#111111' width='5%'>$i</td>
            <td bgcolor='#111111' width='50%'><a href='viewplayer?playerid=$Username'>$Username</a></td>
            <td bgcolor='#333333' width='45%'>$TotalCrimes</a></td></td>
        </tr>
        ";
    } 
?>
```

Comment: @JohnConde - I reviewed the post you think this is a duplicate of and I don't think it is because that echos ALL the users with a rank next to them, I need to echo 1 row from a specific point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to assume that you already have a variable set to hold the current users ID number and total crimes, so in this case I will use `$user` as my variable.

Change yours to fit.

Now, I see 2 instances in which you could mean as your post wasn't very specific, so I will address both.

To show the number at the top of the page, you would use something like;

```
<?php
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `totalcrimes` > '{$user['totalcrimes']}'";
$run   = mysql_query($sql);
$rank  = mysql_num_rows($run) + 1;
echo 'Your rank: ' . $rank;
```

Other than that, I see it's possibly being used to highlight your row, so something like this would suffice;

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$FindCrimes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE status='Alive' AND robot = 0 ORDER BY `totalcrimes` DESC LIMIT 5");
while($Row  = mysql_fetch_assoc($FindCrimes)) 
{
    $Username    = $Row['playername'];
    $TotalCrimes = number_format($Row['totalcrimes']);
    $i++;

    $primary   = '#111111';
    $secondary = '#333333';

    if ($Row['id'] == $user['id']) 
    {
        $primary   = '#222222';
        $secondary = '#444444';
    }

    echo "<tr>
        <td bgcolor='$primary' width='5%'>$i</td>
        <td bgcolor='$primary' width='50%'><a href='viewplayer?playerid=$Username'>$Username</a></td>
        <td bgcolor='$secondary' width='45%'>$TotalCrimes</a></td></td>
    </tr>";
}
```

If neither of those give your requirements, please comment and I'll edit to suit.

`edit`: I've worked on games for a few years - care to share the link to yours?

Comment: Hi Luke thanks for your response I will try these solutions out now and the link to my site is: http://www.societymobsters.com currently in BETA while I am preparing new features etc

Comment: Is that gRPG? Also: `You do not have permission to message an Administrator!` - boo!

Answer (score 0):

This can do the trick

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1 as rank 
FROM users
WHERE totalcrimes > (SELECT totalcrimes 
                     FROM users 
                     WHERE user_id='12345' AND status='Alive' AND robot='0');
```

So it counts all rows with greater `totalcrimes` than selected user (in this example I have used `user_id` column and some id `12345`), than adds 1 on that sum and returns as `rank` value.

Course, modify `WHERE` clause inside the brackets to make it work for you.

I assumed that table name is `users` and user's id is integer `user_id`.

### Test preview (Navicat Premium):

[image]

**What this query does?** It returns number of selected rows + 1 as `rank` column, from the table `users` where `totalcrimes` is greater than `totalcrimes` of some user. That user's totalcrimes is selected by another query (by its `user_id`). If you have multiple users with same `totalcrimes` value, this query will return same rank for all of them.

Comment: this way you don't need value of `totalcrimes` column for that user before you run this query.